# wpf c# background worker works when execution finished

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I have a wpf application where I want to start a loading indicator before a task and end after task done. But the indicator starts after the task executes. 
What I am trying is as follows.

```
      private void RunAllScriptsChildwdwBtnOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(); // this supposed to start progress bar
        _RunAllScripts_Click();

    }

   private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            ... Start loading indicator
        });
    }

    private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,
                                           RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        ... End loading indicator
    }
```

But loading indicator starts and ends (as supposed in worker events) only after 
_RunAllScripts_Click(); method execution is complete.
(I found that after unsubscribing from worker_RunWorkerCompleted event, progress bar starts and stays as is because no code to end it).

Also I want to add that, breakpoint hits worker_DoWork method before the execution, but UI updates after execution as I indicated above.

Thanks for all help you will be able to provide.

Comment: In general, you would probably want to use `async/await` possibly in conjunction with `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run` to accomplish this.

Comment: Dear Sir Haddad, thank you for your comment, I have a knowledge gap ( that I am ashamed of) about async tasks. Can you please elaborate your answer with an example if possible.

Comment: @bugrasitemkar did my suggestion work for you? It should be working

Comment: if the only thing you do in the function is a `this.Dispatcher.Invoke` all you do is make a new thread that as the first thing it does is ask the UI to do more work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear kind people helping me about this subject, thank you all.
This works for me, hope it works for all.

```
BackgroundWorker bwTestAll = new BackgroundWorker() { WorkerReportsProgress = true };

 bwTestAll.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(TestAll);
        bwTestAll.RunWorkerCompleted += TestAll_RunWorkerCompleted;

//this is where I initialize my loading ring and other stuff and marshall background
//worker to do the main work
 Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    EnableLoading = true;
                    RunAllScriptsTest.IsEnabled = false;

                }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);

                bwTestAll.RunWorkerAsync();


//this is my main work
  void TestAll(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        presenter.RunAllScripts(true);
    }

//this is where I do my post-work stuff
 private void TestAll_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,
                                   RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            /
            EnableLoading = false;
            RunAllScriptsTest.IsEnabled = true;
            DbExecGrid = this.ExecutionResults;
            ShowOrHideExecGrid(this.EnableOrDisableGrid);

        }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
    }
```

*Please Notice that Dispatcher with "DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle" works for me.

Answer (score 2):

If i was you i would use the async + await keyword for this

```
    private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // this is where you would enable your indicator
        Button.IsEnabled = false;

        await Task.Run(
            () =>
            {
                // this is where you put your work, which should be executed in the background thread.
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            });

        // this is where you would disable it
        Button.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Dear Dbl you suggestion  does not work sadly,  in await block I am getting an exception: "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." and if i wrap it with dispatcher.Invoke, it behaves as I initially described, only executing code after the task executed

Comment: You could provide more of your code. Looks like there is an access issue, which can probably resolved. Does your Dispatcher Invoke code work correctly then if you wrap it with that?

Answer (score 0):

Using `async/await` will work. The `await` keyword will allow you to run work without affecting/blocking the UI thread (allowing message pumping to still occur). Once the work has finished, any code after the `await` keyword will execute.

Note that I have also wrapped the `await` work in an `InvokeAsync` call, as it appears that additional work you are doing required UI thread access.

```
private async void RunAllScriptsChildwdwBtnOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //TODO  ... Start loading indicator

    await Task.Run(async ()=> 
    {
        await Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(()=>
        {
            _RunAllScripts_Click();
        });
    });

    //TODO  ... End loading indicator
}
```